# How do I solve the iPhone error: <program>"failed to install" when Adhoc distribution used and many successful distributions?

Tags: xcode, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution

I have distributed a number of adhoc distributions to the same devices.  Now when testers try to load the app I get this error.  So far I have defined a new profile ensuring the devices are correct device codes.  I change the signing to reflect the new distribution profile, I have cleaned then generated the archive.  I am against tthe wall since I don't know what could cause this error.  I have tried the solutions mentioned on this site.

Help!!!

Comment: When you are archiving your app, Xcode may be erroneously choosing a development profile to sign with. This is a bug in Xcode. To work around, before you archive, go to your project settings and specifically choose the correct distribution profile for the Release configuration. Also ensure that in your scheme, the Archive action is using the Release configuration.

Comment: Hi Jason, I did as you indicated but it didn't work.  I still get the <program> failedd to install.  I didn't change the other signing seettings.  Should I change those as well.  I only changed the release signing seetting.